# Dividing the interval in subintervals of equal length

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, sorting

I am asked to describe the operation of the processure BUCKET SORT at the array $$A=\langle 0.75, 0.13, 0.16, 0.64, 0.39, 0.20, 0.89, 0.53, 0.71, 0.42, 0.19 \rangle $$

dividing the interval $[0, 1)$ in $10$ subintervals of equal length.

In my book I found the following algorithm:

```
BUCKETSORT(A) 
 n ← length[A] 
 for i ← 1 to n 
     insert A[i] in the chain B[⌊nA[i]⌋] 
 for i ← o to n-1 
     sort the chain B[i] with insertion sort 
 concatenation of the chains B[0], B[1], ... , B[n-1]
```

So, in this case $n=11$, right??

How can we use the fact that we have to divide the interval in $10$ subintervals of equal length??

Answer (score 1):

Your ten subintervals are of the form $[(k-1)/10,k/10)$ where $k = 1, 2, \ldots, 10$. It sounds  like the question is asking you to determine which points go into which buckets, and then perhaps the overall complexity of the algorithm for this data assuming that you are using insertion sort on each bucket.

Comment: So we take $n=10$, right?? But is the for loop till $n$?? At the array $A$ there are $11$ elements...

Comment: Yes, if $n$ is the number of buckets then you would modify the code to set $n = 10$ and then the loop over elements of $A$ would go from $i=1$ up to $i = $
the length of $A$. So you wouldn't use $n$ in the bounds for the for loop over elements of $A$.

Comment: Ok... What does the last command "concatenation of the chains B[0], B[1], ... , B[n-1] " mean??

Comment: Each $B[j]$ is a sorted list / sorted array after you sort them with insertion sort. And all elements of $B[j]$ are bigger than all elements of $B[k]$ if $j > k$. So to get the final sorted array, all you have to do is initialize an array of size $len(A)$ that will store the final sorted array, and first go through $B[0]$ in sorted order and put these items at the front of the final sorted array, and then after these elements then go through $B[1]$ in sorted order and put these items next in the final sorted array, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

This line of the book's algorithm,

```
 n ← length[A]
```

is used in two ways, of which one is not essential to a bucket sort algorithm.
It is used in `for i ← 1 to n`, which determines which elements `A[i]` are sorted—for this purpose, the number *must* be `length[A]`—but it is also used
in the expression `B[⌊nA[i]⌋]`, which says that there are `n` buckets.

The discussion becomes a bit easier if we rewrite the first loop, `for i ← 1 to n`,
as `for i ← 1 to length[A]`, while still using `n` everywhere else.
Then `n` is just the number of buckets.

"Bucket sort" merely means you 
choose *some* number of buckets, which may or may not be a function of the size of the input. Using `n` for the number of buckets *only*,
you could have `n ← length[A]` or `n ← length[A]/2` or `n ← sqrt(length[A])` or
even `n ← 5`.

The choice `n ← length[A]` satisfies the property that the mean number of elements in each bucket will be $1$. I'm not convinced that that's a particularly good choice in general.
In this particular exercise, however, it seems that you are directed to set $n=10$,
which means you don't have to decide what the best value of $n$ would be.

Comment: So in the for loop, $i$ goes till $n$ ?? So do we don't use the last element of $A$ ??

Comment: I was looking at all the uses of `n` _except_ the first one. I now find this book's version of the algorithm doubly objectionable, as it entangles two really very different things under one name, a loop variable and the size of an array, under one name, `n`.